Using Data Azure Studio to add a record to a Postgres table with a column that is PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
Has anyone found a way of adding rows to a Postgres table using the "Edit Data" option on a table when that table has a primary key defined using "PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY".
I get this error

Commit row failed: cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column

I have tried clicking "Show SQL pane" and removing the primary key column from the SELECT list of columns but that says

Initialize edit data session failed: Error: Edit data with custom query is not supported currently.


Use psql and get on with your work?


Initialize edit data session failed: Error: Edit data with custom query is not supported currently.

According to this, it is a bug in Azure Data Studio that may be the reason for the above error.

Commit row failed: cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column

The above error arises when a user tries to insert the value into an IDENTITY column that is created using the "GENERATED ALWAYS" option. To solve this error, use the OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE option while inserting a user-specified value. Instead of using the Edit Data option, use the SQL query tab and run the query using the format below to insert a value into the Identity column:
INSERT INTO students(id, name) 
OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
VALUES (3, 'CC');
SELECT * FROM students

It will insert values into the identity column successfully, as shown below:

For more information, you can refer to this.
